# IIS6 Double-Encoding: Still a Security Vulnerability?

Tags: windows, security, iis

Is Double-Encoding still a security vulnerability on IIS6 as it was in IIS4/5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes and no, Strictly speaking, on the MS-API level, The issue has been rectified. Of course, if your application deals with encoding and requests paths that may not be contingent upon the URI provided - You're vulnerable and you're going to want to provide filtering AFTER any applicable encoding has been done.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with Double-Encoding ? If it you talk about IIS Unicode Vulnerability (explained in http://www.hackingspirits.com/eth-hac/papers/iis_uni.html) , it's been resolved many years ago. IIS 6.0 is not vulnerable to this attack.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [this kind of web application attack](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Double_Encoding), then this is really most often due to a problem in the web application's code and not the web server behaviour. This particular issue is a problem on any and all web servers.